# Java code/ JSP page in wordpress

Tags: forms

Is it possible to write java code or add a Jsp page in word press, I searched on Internet but did not find any solution. I found How to run applet in wordpress But that too was not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No. WordPress is written in PHP which is not Java.

Maybe you can configure your webserver in a way to proxy a certain URL to be handled by some Java Server, but this is definitely not a WordPress issue and would be off topic here. You can try with sister sites like https://serverfault.com/ though.